# How can I set the height of div equal to the next one via jquery?

Tags: jquery

my HTML code is:

```
<div class="col-xs-4 white-bg v-text">
  <div class="">
    <h4>My header</h4>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-8 big-square">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="assets/img/neghab-03.JPG" />
  </a>
</div>
```

and my jquery code is:

```
$(function(){
    $(".v-text").height(($(this).next().height()+"px"));
});
```

I have more than 10 divs in my code with different height. I want all of them have their next div height. My code dosen't work. Could you please help me what's wrong with my jquery code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` in your code isn't anything in particular. You may have meant:

```
$(function(){
    var vtext = $(".v-text");
    vtext.next().height(vtext.height());
});
```

...so that you're calling `height` as a setter on the next div, and as a getter on the `v-text` div. Also note that you don't need to append the `px` when the value is a number, jQuery handles it.

---

Re your comment:

> I have more than 10 divs with different height....

You should have mentioned that in the question. We can use an `each` loop for that:

```
$(function(){
    $(".v-text").each(function() {
        var vtext = $(this);
        vtext.next().height(vtext.height());
    });
});
```

**Live Example:**

```js
var counter = 3;
var timer = setInterval(function() {
  if (--counter === 0) {
    clearInterval(timer);
    $(".v-text").each(function() {
      var vtext = $(this);
      vtext.next().height(vtext.height());
    });
    $("#countdown").text("done");
  } else {
    $("#countdown").text(counter);
  }
}, 800);
```

```css
.v-text,
.big-square {
  background-color: #ed0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="countdown" style="font-weight: bold; color: blue">3</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 white-bg v-text">
      <div class="">
        <h4>My header</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-8 big-square">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ea3e7fb871c61756b961bc56c0478809?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" />
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 white-bg v-text">
      <div class="">
        <h4>My header<br>Bigger</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-8 big-square">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ea3e7fb871c61756b961bc56c0478809?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" />
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 white-bg v-text">
      <div class="">
        <h4>My header<br>Much<br>Bigger</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-8 big-square">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ea3e7fb871c61756b961bc56c0478809?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" />
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Of course, that will only make their heights equal when the DOM has been parsed, not later if an image inside the `v-text` element is loaded and changes its height, or if the user resizes the browser and changes the height.

Comment: Thanks. But I have more than 10 divs with different height. should I set a new class for all of them and in jquery add all of them?

Comment: @atousadarabi: You should have mentioned that in the question. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @atousadarabi: Updated.

Comment: Thanks alot yes It wroked :)